# Two tables having same composite key

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql, plsql

I have tow tables with same composite key.
Following is the table

table T1

```
No  |  Date        |  S_hour
----+---------------+-------
1   |  2012-01-01  |  8
1   |  2012-01-02  |  8
1   |  2012-01-03  |  8
2   |  2012-01-01  |  8
2   |  2012-01-02  |  8
2   |  2012-01-03  |  8
```

table T2

```
No  |  Date        |  L_hour
----+---------------+-------
1   |  2012-01-01  |  8
1   |  2012-01-02  |  3
1   |  2012-01-03  |  8
2   |  2012-01-01  |  2
2   |  2012-01-02  |  8
2   |  2012-01-03  |  8
```

S_hour is scheduled hour and L_hour is leave hour.

In my Query out put I want  S_hour - L_hour.Following should be query output
Query output

```
No  |  Date        |  S_hour - L_hour
----+---------------+-------
1   |  2012-01-01  |  0
1   |  2012-01-02  |  5
1   |  2012-01-03  |  0
2   |  2012-01-01  |  6
2   |  2012-01-02  |  0
2   |  2012-01-03  |  0
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your tags are conflicting: MySQL, SQL Server's T-SQL, and Oracle's PL/SQL.  Which one is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  t1.No
,       t1.Date
,       t1.S_hour - t2.L_hour
from    Table1 t1
join    Table2 t2
on      t1.No = t2.No
        and t1.Date = t2.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
 SELECT T1.No, T1.Date, s_hour - L_hour AS result
 FROM T1 INNER JOIN
 T2 ON t1.No = t2.No AND 
 T1.Date = T2.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Query:

```
SELECT t1.no, t1.date1, t1.s_hour - t2.l_hour FROM t1, t2 
WHERE t1.no=t2.no AND t1.date1=t2.date1;
```

Fiddle: [**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1e63d/2)